# How can I figure out if a given device supports PoE?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am looking at different power-line adapters (that transmit Ethernet signal over the normal electric network in the house) and I am considering to plug a PoE switch to one of these. How can I figure out if the adapter supports PoE?

Answer (score 1):

Any of these Powerline will support this as it is the switch with PoE that provides the actual power to the device(s).  The Powerline ethernet devices simply replace a run of cable or a WiFi connection.

You simply connect ethernet at each end and then connect your PoE switch.

I use several different Powerline Ethernet devices and have not seen any that also provide PoE.  However, I am sure someone will add the information if such exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but to be honest I don't understand it. You are saying that these Powerline adapters do support PoE, or they don't?

Comment: @Grzenio 1.5 years late, you can thank SO "related" - PoE and powerline adapters are not synonymous. A powerline adapter may support PoE (i.e. PoE is integrated), if it says it does, but Dave M is saying these configurations are rare. If the switch is powered by PoE, then the powerline adapter must be identified as providing PoE; however I believe Dave M's reply assumes your switch provides PoE to the connected devices ("downstream" relative to the switch) but does not draw power from the powerline adapter ("upstream" relative to the switch).